# spring boot request doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I've just started Spring Boot course with Java Brains https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRFCeRVWCNE&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTbx8p2oCgcAQGQyqN8XeA1x&index=11

I've got a problem. This is very simple app and I've done everything like is in the tutorial but I still getting the 404 response.
I followed tips from comments but it still fail :(

Could you review this? Maybe you will see what is wrong with that. I am using Spring Tool Suite, Server starts correctly.

Here is my code for main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "<io.javabrains.springbootstarter.hello>")
public class CourseApiApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(CourseApiApp.class, args);

  }

 }
```

And for the controller:

```
    @RestController
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String sayHi() {
    return "Hi";
}
}
```

Hope you can help me. Greetings :)

Comment: what is the url you are hitting ? please provide us

Comment: localhost:8080/hello

Comment: are you sure that the application mapped your controller ? look at the console if your class mapped successfully

Comment: Ok, I've solve it... I had a syntax error in basePackages declaration... I didn't need this <>. I spent on that 1 hour. I love programming :D

Comment: also remove  '<' &  '>' Characters  and keep the package name as it is with no additional charachters

Comment: glad to hear that good luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `<>` brackets from your package deceleration in component scan

@ComponentScan(basePackages = "io.javabrains.springbootstarter.hello")